# Is there a way to do fraction in sympy

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sympy

I am trying to do fraction using sympy, I know sympy is supports symbolic but can it be done with old fraction, please know that I want it to be display it as unevaluatedexpr here is my code.

```
from sympy import *
s = (3)/(2) + (4) / (6)
display(s)
init_printing()
```

Comment: `sympy.Rational(numerator, denominator)`

Comment: but can you please show me in action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
>>> import sympy
>>> a = sympy.Rational(3, 2)
>>> b = sympy.Rational(4, 6)
>>> a
3/2
>>> b
2/3
```

Comment: what about mixed numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Alhamdulilaah I found it how to do it this is how you do it

```
from sympy import *



r = Rational(3,2)+Rational(4,2)

display(r)
```